# How to import CSS successfully into Polymer

Tags: javascript, polymer

This is a bit of a 101 question, but I am trying to externalize my css styling from my HTLM polymer code into a separate CSS file.

From what I can make out this can be done through a `.css` file if you import it within a template element.

Eg

```
 <template> 
   <link rel="stylesheet" href="mystyles.css">
   ....
 </template>
```

However, it appears that styles of elements I import and use from Polymer take precedent. So for example I may

1. create style in my mystyles.css

   ```
   .my-background { 
      background: #4fc3f7;
   }
   ```
2. and then apply it

   ```
   paper-fab class="my-background"..>...
   ```

But the background of paper-fab is unaffected, being override by the style of paper-fab.

Apologies, as various articles do go along way to explaining the use of styles in Polymer. But none are explicit and simple enough to say "if you used to import styles in the past like this..... then now do it like so..."

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Stylesheet should be imported inside your dom-module, but outside the template. Also, you should specify `rel="import` and `type="css"`. You can find more information in the [documentation](https://www.polymer-project.org/1.0/docs/devguide/styling.html#external-stylesheets).

```
<dom-module id="test-element">
    <link rel="import" type="css" href="mystyles.css">
    <template>
        <paper-fab class="my-background">Test</paper-fab>
    </template>
</dom-module>
```

**Update**
External stylesheets have been deprecated. From the documentation:

> This experimental feature is now deprecated in favor of [style modules](https://www.polymer-project.org/1.0/docs/devguide/styling.html#style-modules). It is still supported, but support will be removed in the future.

Comment: Thanks @Maria I have, in the mean time been play with that and have discovered it does work. Thank you for validating it!

Comment: @Maria Thank you, The value of the type attribute should be a MIME type such as text/html, text/css, and so on. https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/link

Comment: @Ali.MD The Polymer documentation explicitly says `type="css"` so that's what I used. But it does indeed contradict the documentation from MDN that you have linked. Then again, the feature has been deprecated in Polymer, so it's best to move on from that, I guess.

Comment: @Maria I did not see! but its can be polymer document mistake. it must be mime type.